# How do I create a query that list the name of students who took fewer than three classes or have a null value for class

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a "database" with two tables a student,and enroll. The student table has stuid, lastname, firstname. The enroll table has stuid classnumber and grade.

I have to return a list that looks like this

Last Name
Burns
Jones
Lee
McCarthy
Rivera
Smith

First Name

Edward 
Mary
Perry
Owen
Jane
Tom

I attempted to do a statement like this

`Select lastname, firstname
Where Not exists (Select stuid from enroll e where e.stuid = s.stuid)
Having count(*) < 3
Group By lastname, firstname;`

I understand that I need two merge the two tables basically so that I get the results of people who have classes < 3 and people who are also not currently enrolled in a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and `HAVING`

```
 SELECT st.stuid, lastname, firstname 
 FROM student st 
 LEFT JOIN enroll el ON st.stuid = el.stuid 
 GROUP BY st.stuid 
 HAVING count(el.stuid) < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
SELECT lastname, firstname FROM student st LEFT JOIN enroll el 
ON st.stuid = el.stid 
WHERE (el.classnumber < 3 OR el.classnumber IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "where clause " needs to come after your "from clause". Then try this !

```
 select firstname , lastname
 from student s join enroll e 
 on s.stuid = e.stuid
 Where e.classnumber < 3 and e.classnumber is null
```